# H264-Encoded Video Not Playing In Android App (Using Expo)

Tags: video, react-native, h.264, expo

I am trying to build a video app for Android using the Expo/React Native Framework.

To totally isolate things, I have something like the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Video } from 'expo'

class VideoPlayer extends Component {

  render = () => {
    return (
      <Video
        source={{ uri: "https://storage.googleapis.com/deepthought-collective.appspot.com/testvid.mp4" }}
        rate={1.0}
        volume={1.0}
        isMuted={false}
        resizeMode="cover"
        shouldPlay
        isLooping
        style={{ width: 300, height: 500 }}
      />
    )
  }

}
```

In IOS, this plays fine. On Android, I get audio, but no video (just white).

This is the output of ffprobe:

```
> ffprobe testvid.mp4
ffprobe version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'testvid.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.56.100
  Duration: 00:00:09.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2691 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 720x1280, 2522 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

I have tested this on a few Android devices, as well as an emulator, and observed the same result.

The video was produced using OBS.

If I open it on Chrome or download it, it doesn't even play sound.

Does anybody have any idea why it might be playing this way on Android, or have any recommendations how to encode video for Android?

Comment: Tooling around with this a bit, it seems like resizing to 360x640, the video will play. Does anybody know if there's some kind of max resolution for video on Android?

Answer (score 0):

Different devices may have different support, but the the set that should be supported across all platforms, for given Android version, is listed here:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html

H.264 has many different parameters so one h.264 encoded video with one set of parameters may play and another h.264 encoded video may not. The h.264 standard include the concept of profiles which are like a group of parameters of attributes for a different encoding. You can see a list of some of the profiles here:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC

In your case your video is using 'high' profile. This is not included in the set of default supported encoding at the link above - this may be the issue, or at least one of the issues you are seeing.

As a general rule, baseline is nearly always supported across devices and main is generally supported - main provides more compression than baseline, at the expense of more processing to encode and decode.

You can test if this is the issue by re-encoding your video with main or baseline profile and testing it again.